# Please someone help me with WHEA_UNCORRECTABLE_ERROR

Tags: power-supply

Randomly, my PC initiated abrupt shutdowns exclusively during gaming sessions, accompanied by a bluescreen displaying the WHEA_UNCORRECTABLE_ERROR, followed by an automatic restart. Despite initially dismissing it as an isolated incident, the issue persisted consistently upon every subsequent gaming endeavor. I undertook the measure of reinstalling Windows, yet this failed to resolve the problem. The occurrence manifested unpredictably, whether during the loading screen, gameplay, or even Fortnite landings.

Subsequent diagnostics, including the execution of MEMTEST68, ruled out memory concerns, confirming the integrity of both DDR4 RAM modules. Evaluations of the CPU through Intel's diagnostic software and Cinebench yielded no crashes. Similarly, FurMark assessments demonstrated the GPU's stability with no discernible issues. Intriguingly, simultaneous stress tests involving Cinebench and FurMark exhibited system stability, despite games typically not exerting comparable stress on these components.

The focus has shifted towards a potential power-related anomaly, particularly with the GPU drawing power within normal parameters. Concerns arose about the 12V rail, although monitoring software compatibility issues hindered direct assessment. However, the BIOS readings indicated nominal 12V and 5V rail values, consistent with specifications. Despite meticulous cable reinstallation, the issue persisted. While inclined to suspect the power supply unit (PSU), the discrepancy arises in its compatibility with stress-inducing tasks like Cinebench and FurMark.

Recently I have managed to find the WHEA LOGGER ERROR processor code event id 18 in the event viewer. Any insights on the meaning of this ?

The prevailing confusion lies in the incongruity between stable performance during concurrent Cinebench and FurMark usage and the recurrent crashes during any gaming activity. Contemplating the acquisition of a new PSU, I seek assistance in resolving this perplexing and frustrating predicament. Any guidance or insights into a potential solution would be greatly appreciated.

My parts:

- Rog strix oc 3080 10gb
- i5 13600kf
- gigabyte b760 ax ddr4
- crucial p5 plus 1tb (operating system)
- crucial p3 plus 2tb (all my games)
- nzxt h5 elite case
- nzxt x53 rgb liquid cooler
- corsair 32gb ddr4 rgb pro sl
- msi a750gf (i use default psu cables)

Details of one of the whea logger events:

```
Log Name:      System
Source:        Microsoft-Windows-WHEA-Logger
Date:          01/02/2024 06:42:32
Event ID:      18
Task Category: None
Level:         Error
Keywords:      
User:          LOCAL SERVICE
Computer:      DESKTOP-DPMH1HN
Description:
A fatal hardware error has occurred.

Reported by component: Processor Core
Error Source: Machine Check Exception
Error Type: Cache Hierarchy Error
Processor APIC ID: 0
```

The details view of this entry contains further information.
Event XML:

```
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="Microsoft-Windows-WHEA-Logger" Guid="{c26c4f3c-3f66-4e99-8f8a-39405cfed220}" />
    <EventID>18</EventID>
    <Version>0</Version>
    <Level>2</Level>
    <Task>0</Task>
    <Opcode>0</Opcode>
    <Keywords>0x8000000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2024-02-01T14:42:32.3373493Z" />
    <EventRecordID>5933</EventRecordID>
    <Correlation ActivityID="{31c761f9-ef62-468f-8b8a-ea3cd84d8ca5}" />
    <Execution ProcessID="5500" ThreadID="6452" />
    <Channel>System</Channel>
    <Computer>DESKTOP-DPMH1HN</Computer>
    <Security UserID="S-1-5-19" />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data Name="ErrorSource">3</Data>
    <Data Name="ApicId">0</Data>
    <Data Name="MCABank">0</Data>
    <Data Name="MciStat">0xb6000000480f0150</Data>
    <Data Name="MciAddr">0xd375d373</Data>
    <Data Name="MciMisc">0x0</Data>
    <Data Name="ErrorType">9</Data>
    <Data Name="TransactionType">0</Data>
    <Data Name="Participation">256</Data>
    <Data Name="RequestType">5</Data>
    <Data Name="MemorIO">256</Data>
    <Data Name="MemHierarchyLvl">0</Data>
    <Data Name="Timeout">256</Data>
    <Data Name="OperationType">256</Data>
    <Data Name="Channel">256</Data>
    <Data Name="Length">936</Data>
    <Data Name="RawData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ata>
  </EventData>
</Event>
```

Details of kernel power event:

```
Log Name:      System
Source:        Microsoft-Windows-Kernel-Power
Date:          01/02/2024 05:27:51
Event ID:      41
Task Category: (63)
Level:         Critical
Keywords:      (70368744177664),(2)
User:          SYSTEM
Computer:      DESKTOP-DPMH1HN
Description:
The system has rebooted without cleanly shutting down first. This error could be caused if the system stopped responding, crashed, or lost power unexpectedly.
Event Xml:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="Microsoft-Windows-Kernel-Power" Guid="{331c3b3a-2005-44c2-ac5e-77220c37d6b4}" />
    <EventID>41</EventID>
    <Version>8</Version>
    <Level>1</Level>
    <Task>63</Task>
    <Opcode>0</Opcode>
    <Keywords>0x8000400000000002</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2024-02-01T13:27:51.8024703Z" />
    <EventRecordID>5167</EventRecordID>
    <Correlation />
    <Execution ProcessID="4" ThreadID="8" />
    <Channel>System</Channel>
    <Computer>DESKTOP-DPMH1HN</Computer>
    <Security UserID="S-1-5-18" />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data Name="BugcheckCode">292</Data>
    <Data Name="BugcheckParameter1">0x0</Data>
    <Data Name="BugcheckParameter2">0xffff85881f77a028</Data>
    <Data Name="BugcheckParameter3">0xb6000000</Data>
    <Data Name="BugcheckParameter4">0x480f0150</Data>
    <Data Name="SleepInProgress">0</Data>
    <Data Name="PowerButtonTimestamp">0</Data>
    <Data Name="BootAppStatus">0</Data>
    <Data Name="Checkpoint">0</Data>
    <Data Name="ConnectedStandbyInProgress">false</Data>
    <Data Name="SystemSleepTransitionsToOn">1</Data>
    <Data Name="CsEntryScenarioInstanceId">0</Data>
    <Data Name="BugcheckInfoFromEFI">false</Data>
    <Data Name="CheckpointStatus">0</Data>
    <Data Name="CsEntryScenarioInstanceIdV2">0</Data>
    <Data Name="LongPowerButtonPressDetected">false</Data>
  </EventData>
</Event>
```

Multiple errors in event viewer that I never noticed:

Page 1
[image: Page 1]

Page 2
[image: Page 2]

Page 3
[image: Page 3]

Something is definitely wrong and I think it is the power supply, any thoughts?

**Update 1**: 12v rail and all is fine, still baffled why it happened, also reinstalled windows clean so that might have helped:

[image]

Issue fixed until it happens again I guess. Problem I think was that I had another 2tb nvme. Could have drawn too much power because I took it out now and Fortnite is running perfectly.

**Update 2**: It happened again on fortnite opening, not sure how a reinstall helped at all to be honest.

**Event properties of most recent example**:

Kernel Power Critical Error ID 41:

[image: Kernel Power Critical Error ID 41]

```
    Log Name:      System
Source:        Microsoft-Windows-Kernel-Power
Date:          02/02/2024 23:23:25
Event ID:      41
Task Category: (63)
Level:         Critical
Keywords:      (70368744177664),(2)
User:          SYSTEM
Computer:      DESKTOP-10JOBPJ
Description:
The system has rebooted without cleanly shutting down first. This error could be caused if the system stopped responding, crashed, or lost power unexpectedly.
Event Xml:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="Microsoft-Windows-Kernel-Power" Guid="{331c3b3a-2005-44c2-ac5e-77220c37d6b4}" />
    <EventID>41</EventID>
    <Version>9</Version>
    <Level>1</Level>
    <Task>63</Task>
    <Opcode>0</Opcode>
    <Keywords>0x8000400000000002</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2024-02-03T07:23:25.6856688Z" />
    <EventRecordID>1214</EventRecordID>
    <Correlation />
    <Execution ProcessID="4" ThreadID="8" />
    <Channel>System</Channel>
    <Computer>DESKTOP-10JOBPJ</Computer>
    <Security UserID="S-1-5-18" />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data Name="BugcheckCode">292</Data>
    <Data Name="BugcheckParameter1">0x0</Data>
    <Data Name="BugcheckParameter2">0xffffdd8f02b75028</Data>
    <Data Name="BugcheckParameter3">0xb6000000</Data>
    <Data Name="BugcheckParameter4">0x480f0150</Data>
    <Data Name="SleepInProgress">0</Data>
    <Data Name="PowerButtonTimestamp">0</Data>
    <Data Name="BootAppStatus">0</Data>
    <Data Name="Checkpoint">0</Data>
    <Data Name="ConnectedStandbyInProgress">false</Data>
    <Data Name="SystemSleepTransitionsToOn">0</Data>
    <Data Name="CsEntryScenarioInstanceId">1</Data>
    <Data Name="BugcheckInfoFromEFI">false</Data>
    <Data Name="CheckpointStatus">0</Data>
    <Data Name="CsEntryScenarioInstanceIdV2">1</Data>
    <Data Name="LongPowerButtonPressDetected">false</Data>
    <Data Name="LidReliability">false</Data>
    <Data Name="InputSuppressionState">0</Data>
    <Data Name="PowerButtonSuppressionState">0</Data>
    <Data Name="LidState">3</Data>
  </EventData>
</Event>
```

[image: WHEA Logger Error Error ID 1]

```
    Log Name:      System
Source:        Microsoft-Windows-WHEA-Logger
Date:          02/02/2024 23:23:33
Event ID:      1
Task Category: None
Level:         Error
Keywords:      WHEA Error Event Logs
User:          LOCAL SERVICE
Computer:      DESKTOP-10JOBPJ
Description:
A fatal hardware error has occurred. A record describing the condition is contained in the data section of this event.
Event Xml:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="Microsoft-Windows-WHEA-Logger" Guid="{c26c4f3c-3f66-4e99-8f8a-39405cfed220}" />
    <EventID>1</EventID>
    <Version>0</Version>
    <Level>2</Level>
    <Task>0</Task>
    <Opcode>0</Opcode>
    <Keywords>0x8000000000000002</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2024-02-03T07:23:33.6309064Z" />
    <EventRecordID>1291</EventRecordID>
    <Correlation ActivityID="{0b2749ee-9575-4bdc-91be-91e68a7e4d81}" />
    <Execution ProcessID="4520" ThreadID="4804" />
    <Channel>System</Channel>
    <Computer>DESKTOP-10JOBPJ</Computer>
    <Security UserID="S-1-5-19" />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data Name="Length">1019</Data>
    <Data Name="RawData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ata>
  </EventData>
</Event>
```

**Update 3**: Updated BIOS to firmware F9 and didn't solve anything
**Update 4**: After swapping the psu cables around going into the gpu, ie: 2 are normal cables on is able to daisychain, the pc did not even blue screen when opening fortnite, just completely turned off and on again. On my main screen the blue screen was showing but on my second monitor this is what I saw this weird bug during the BSOD.
**Update 5**: Now my PC blue screens every time I turn it on and it attempts to repair itself but fails. I think it is best to take it a professional to fix it. If you guys no something I don't that would be great.
**Update 5**: The BSOD now only happens when opening a game. I cannot run a game without it crashing when opening and going straight into a BSOD

[image: this weird bug during the BSO]

Comment: Please give some readable form to your post, and also publish online the `.dmp` files that you can find in `%SystemRoot%\Minidump`.

Comment: @Iason - You are going to need to improve the quality of the question.  Be sure each sentence is clear, grammatically correct, and does not contain shorthand or misspelled words.  You should also use paragraphs to separate major statements.  Essentionally the question should flow better, once you have made those improvements to the body of the question, check the box next to `This edit resolves the original close reason and the question should be considered for reopening.` so the question can be reviewed and be potentially reopened.  Question cannot be answered until it's reopened.

Comment: `WHEA_UNCORRECTABLE_ERROR` is a hardware error AFAIK. As to the PSU, simply looking at the voltage values of the 12V and 5V rails doesn't determine whether there's an issue there, only that 12V and 5V are being supplied. For the 12V/5V rails, two things must be done: **(1)** add up the maximum current rating for all hardware attached to each 12V and 5V rail _circuit_, ensuring it's below the maximum current rating for each rail; **(2)** either test with a known good PSU or use a multimeter on the correct _fused_ lead hole to measure the current draw while the machine is being used for gaming

Comment: Where do I plug in the multimeter because last time I did that while the pc was running my whole pc shut off instantly and the psu clicked, luckily still working but don’t know what damage i did @JW0914

Comment: @Iason Easiest way I've found is to use an unused 4pin Molex and insert the metal end of the black lead into the back of the Molex connector with the black wire(s) _(this should create a small amount of friction to keep the lead in place against the Molex pin - verify by setting the multimeter to Continuity and touching any other ground point, incl. a metal part of the case, with the red lead)_, then do the same with the red lead into the back of Molex for the yellow [12V] and red [5V] wires _(continuity can be tested with any other power connecter on the same 12V/5V rail circuit)_

Comment: @Iason _(Cont'd...)_ Some multimeters will only do 10A on the fused lead hole, so if this is the case with yours, either a dedicated amperage monitor would need to be used, else a known good PSU _(a no-contact current multimeter could be tried (it has a clamp like top that goes around a wire) since it uses EMF to determine current, but with the 12V and 5V wires being so close to each other, it may create an issue)_

Comment: Is there a video to demonstrate this better because I don’t want to take a risk, my molex cable that I tried have black wires going  into it. I had followed a video and copied the person but it didn’t work and turned off my pc possibly causing irreversible damages to the psu. At this point it is 100% a power issue. Gpu lights are flashing red sometimes above the pcie cable slot. Randomly shutting off and showing hundreds of critical Kernel Power Issues in event viewer. I’ve paid at least 10 visits to safe mode in an attempt to get the WHEA logger error in mini dump to open with WinDBG

Comment: (Cont)… and nothing worked. I used Intel Processor Diagnostic Tool and it passed. Even got a boot failure and I don’t know what that means in terms of the issue

Comment: @Iason It's not possible for a multimeter to cause damage to equipment, as it's _measuring_ voltage/current/continuity/resistance, _not_ outputting power to the equipment.

Comment: So then why did the pc instantly turn off and the psu clicked? Also when I had the pc off and did that it couldn’t turn on.

Comment: @Iason Something wass being done incorrectly, because there's no way a multimeter would cause the reported symptoms, unless the metal lead touching a power pin was also contacting another bare wire or ground point, or the metal lead touching a ground pin was contacting a a bare wire/pin supplying voltage. Beyond that, the reported symptoms aren't due to the multimeter.

Comment: Do I need to plug the black and red pin all the way in to the molex cable? Ps I have never used a multimeter before as I borrowed it from a friend so I don’t know the correct settings.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151291/discussion-between-jw0914-and-iason).